# trying to understand sort(key = ...) function

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
employees = [
    {'Name': Allan, 'Age': 25, 'Salary': 10000},
    {'Name': Sharon, 'Age': 30, 'Salary': 8000},
    {'Name': John, 'Age': 18, 'Salary': 1000} 
]
```

And I want to sort this list by taking the 'Name' key as reference. For this purpose, the source I've ben studying has given the following function:

```
def get_name(employee):
    return employee.get('Name')

employees.sort(key = get_name)
```

If I now run print(employees), it sorts out the dictionary as I want to.

My question here is, how does the interpreter understands, what the parameter 'employee' is? It is nowhere defined and it has actually nothing to do with the list "employees". It is a bit confusing for me.

I would appreciate, if anybody explains it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand what `get_name(employees[0])` would do? (If not give it a try!)

Comment: `employee` is whatever parameter `get_name()` was called with.  It has no meaning outside of that function.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` defines what it will do with `key`. `sort` expects `key` to be a *callable* (i.e. function), which it will call and pass one element of the list to it. `sort` will call `key` for each element in the list. The function that you pass (`get_name`) must match this definition, not the other way around.

`employee` in `def get_name(employee)` is an arbitrary parameter name. You define the function, you can name your parameters anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

`employee` is the name the code's author gave to the function `get_name`'s parameter, and it was likely chosen to make the relation to the outer structure clearer. You could replace `employee` in the function (in both places) with any valid variable name and it will work the same:

```py
def get_name(my_dict):
    return my_dict.get('Name')
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `employee` is just the name of the variable given to the `get_name` function; you could change it to `foo` or whatever else and it would still work, as long as you changed it in the function body as well.

As for how the interpreter knows what `employee` is: Python is [duck typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). You could put in a completely different type of variable to the `get_name` function, and as long as it has a `get` method that can take the `'Name'` argument, it'll work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to put names in quotes, otherwise it's illegal in python.

Then maybe this will make it easier to understand:

```
>>> employees = [
...     {'Name': 'Allan', 'Age': 25, 'Salary': 10000},
...     {'Name': 'Sharon', 'Age': 30, 'Salary': 8000},
...     {'Name': 'John', 'Age': 18, 'Salary': 1000} 
... ]
>>> 
>>> sorted( employees, key = lambda x : x['Name'] )
[
    {'Salary': 10000, 'Age': 25, 'Name': 'Allan'},
    {'Salary': 1000, 'Age': 18, 'Name': 'John'},
    {'Salary': 8000, 'Age': 30, 'Name': 'Sharon'}
]
```

Make note, I don't use any external function, just the lambda, which has no name, just a single parameter (`x` in our case), that's one of the items on your list, and it returns the `key` according to which the list will be sorted. You may try to return `x['Salary']` or `x['Age']` and see the result. The name `get_name` is quite accidental and has absolutely no influence. Things are actually much easier with lambdas.